# How solutions of distinct non-negative solutions are there to $k_1+\cdots+k_n=k$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> How many distinct $n$-tuples with distinct non-negative integer elements are there that add to $k$.

For example there are $6$ triples that add to $4$. Namely $(0, 1, 3)$ and its $6$ permutations. Is there a formula for this amount? I have tried very hard to do it but with no luck.

This question can also be rephrased as:

> How many sets of non-negative solutions are there to $k_1+\cdots+k_n=k$ where $k_i\ne k_j$.

It is obvious that the smallest $k$ would be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

---

Another example would be

How many pairs of distinct non-negative integers are there that add to $6$? Clearly this is the number of compositions of length $2$ with distinct terms and $2!$ times the number of compositions of length $1$ with distinct terms (how to count the zeros). We get

> $0+6$, $1+5$, $2+3$, $3+2$, $5+1$, $6+0$

So there are $6$ such pairs.

---

I should note that the answer may be given in terms of the partition function. Which gives how many ways can an integer be written as a sum of positive .integers.

Comment: That's an extremely difficult question... Look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to get an idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By way  of enrichment I would like  to point out that  using the Polya
Enumeration Theorem the closed form is also given by

$$n! [z^k] Z(P_n)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$

where  $Z(P_n) = Z(A_n)-Z(S_n)$  is the  difference between  the cycle
index of  the alternating group and  the cycle index  of the symmetric
group. This cycle index is known in species theory as the set operator
$\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ and the species equation here is

$$\mathfrak{P}_{=n}\left(\mathcal{E}  +  \mathcal{Z}  +  \mathcal{Z}^2  +
\mathcal{Z^3} + \cdots\right).$$

Recall  the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(P_n)$ of
the set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ on $n$ slots, which is
$$Z(P_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l-1} a_l Z(P_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$
This recurrence lets us calculate the cycle index $Z(P_n)$ very easily.

For example when $n=3$ as in the introduction to the problem the cycle
index is
$$Z(P_3) = 
1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}-1/2\,a_{{2}}a_{{1}}+1/3\,a_{{3}} $$
and the generating function becomes
$$1/6\, \left( 1-z \right) ^{-3}-1/2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) }}+1/3\, \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right) ^
{-1} $$
which gives the sequence
$$0, 0, 6, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 42, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96,\ldots$$
which is six times [OEIS A069905](https://oeis.org/A069905).

Similarly when $n=5$ we get the cycle index
$$Z(P_5) = 
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}}{120}}-1/12\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{
3}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}\\-1/4\,a_{{4}}a_{{1}}-1/
6\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}+1/5\,a_{{5}}$$
and the generating function becomes
$${\frac {1}{120\, \left( 1-z \right) ^{5}}}-1/12\,{\frac {1}{
 \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}\\+1/6\,{
\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{2}}}+1
/8\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2} \left( 1-z
 \right) }}-1/4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{4}+1 \right)  \left( 1-
z \right) }}\\-1/6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( -
{z}^{3}+1 \right) }}+1/5\, \left( -{z}^{5}+1 \right) ^{-1}$$
which gives the sequence
$$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 240, 360, 600, \ldots$$
which is $120$ times [OEIS A001401](https://oeis.org/A001401).

The prefix of zeroes (these two examples start at one) 
compared to the two OEIS entries represents the fact that
the minimum value attainable with $n$ distinct summands in
$$[z^k] Z(P_n)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$
is $0+1+2+\cdots+n-1 = 1/2\times n\times (n-1).$

These sequences match the formula by @bof, which is
$$n! p_n\left(k - \frac{1}{2} n (n - 3)\right).$$

There are many more related links at 
[MSE Meta on Burnside/Polya](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868#13335).

The Maple code for these was as follows.

```
p :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;
    if n<k then return 0 fi;

    p(n-1, k-1)+p(n-k,k)
end;

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        local p, s;
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;



pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
        local p, s;
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l-1)*
        a[l]*pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

q1 :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
    local gf;

    gf := pet_varinto_cind(1/(1-z), pet_cycleind_set(n));
    n!*coeftayl(gf, z=0, k);
end;


q2 :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
    n!*p(k-n*(n-3)/2, n);
end;
```

**Addendum.**  As per  request  we now  give  a mixed  (combinatorial,
algebraic) proof of the identity
$$[z^n] Z(P_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= p_k\left(n - \frac{1}{2} k(k-3)\right).$$

*Observe that we have reverted to the standard convention of using $n$
for the sum of the partition and $k$ for the number of parts.*

By the same construction as before (PET) we have
$$p_k\left(n - \frac{1}{2} k(k-3)\right) =
[z^{n- \frac{1}{2} k(k-3)}] Z(S_k)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$
with $Z(S_k)$ being the cycle index of the symmetric group (unlabelled
multisets with operator $\mathfrak{M}_{=k}$.)

Using basic algebra this becomes
$$[z^{n- \frac{1}{2} k(k-3)}] z^k Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= [z^{n- \frac{1}{2} k(k-3) -\frac{1}{2} 2k}] 
Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = [z^{n- \frac{1}{2} k(k-1)}] 
Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

But this is the species
$$\mathfrak{M}_{=k}\left(\mathcal{E}  + \mathcal{Z} +  \mathcal{Z}^2 +
\mathcal{Z^3} + \cdots\right),$$
i.e. partitions with empty constitutents being permitted and 
constituents not necessarily distinct.

There  is  however  a   straighforward  bijection  between  these  and
partitions with  potentially empty  but distinct constituents.   To go
from the former to the latter add $q$ circles on the left of every row
in the Ferrers  diagram with row indices $q$ starting  at zero. Now if
we had two  adjacent rows with the first above  the second with length
$b_1$ and $a_1$ where $b_1\ge  a_1$ then the resulting pair is $b_1+q$
and $a_1+q-1.$ The difference between these is $b_1-a_1+1\ge 1$ so the
new pair is distinct and  in non-decreasing order seen from below.  To
go from  the latter to  the former remove  $q$ circles from  every row
(index is $q$),  turning $b_2$ and $a_2$ where  $b_2>a_2$ into $b_2-q$
and $a_2 -(q-1).$  The difference is $b_2-a_2-1\ge 0$  and the pair is
non-decreasing order but not necessarily distinct.
The number  of circles  being added/removed is
$$\sum_{q=0}^{k-1} q =  \frac{1}{2} k(k-1).$$

We have shown that
$$ [z^{n- \frac{1}{2} k(k-1)}] Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= [z^n] Z(P_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$
Here we have $n\ge \frac{1}{2} k (k-1),$ both sides are zero otherwise.
This concludes the argument.

Comment: Hi! Your answer *is* an enrichment. Thanks for the nice link into MSE Meta. +1

Comment: The sequences match but does there exist a derivation?

Comment: @Alizter Please find the requested proof in the addendum above.

Comment: Marko thank you for your answer. I have left the question unaccepted in order not to discourage any further contribution. Enjoy your bounty.

Comment: Another request. Could you add the generating function for the closed form as well?

Comment: Isn't this just a coefficient extractor applied to the standard partition generating function? Did I understand this correctly? You may want to try this yourself.

Answer (score 9):

This is really just a commentary on yashg's (now deleted) answer; I just want to provide a bit of context and a reference.

To save repetition: all variables in this post are restricted to integers.

The title of the question is somewhat confusing: the vector $(0,1,3)$ is a **solution**, not a "set of solutions", of the multivariable equation $k_1+k_2+k_3=4$. You are asking for the number of solutions of the equation $k_1+\cdots+k_n=k$ where $k_1,\dots,k_n$ are distinct nonnegative integers. By the way, I believe it's usual in the literature (at least, in the Wikipedia reference I'm about to give) to interchange the roles of $k$ and $n$ in such problems.

The answer is in terms of the much-studied [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) $p_k(n)$ which is defined as the number of solutions of the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ where $x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots\ge x_k\ge1$; those solutions are called the *partitions of $n$ into (exactly) $k$ parts*. For fixed $k$, the generating function is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k(n)x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^k)}.$$
For $n\ge k\gt1$ we have the recurrence equation
$$p_k(n)=p_{k-1}(n-1)+p_k(n-k),$$
since $p_{k-1}(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts with smallest part equal to $1$, while $p_k(n-k)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts $\ge2$. Using the recurrence equation and the obvious boundary conditions $p_k(n)=0$ for $n\lt k$ and $p_1(n)=1$ for $n\gt0$, we can calculate values of $p(n,k)$, and derive closed formulas for fixed $k$, e.g., $p_2(n)=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, $p_3(n)=\lfloor\frac{n^2+3}{12}\rfloor$, etc.

Next, the transformation $y_j=x_j+1-k+j$ shows that the number of solutions of the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ with $x_1\gt x_2\gt\cdots\gt x_k\ge0$ is the same as the number of solutions of $y_1+\cdots+y_k=n-\frac{k(k-3)}2$ with $y_1\ge y_2\ge\cdots\ge y_k\ge1$, that is, $p_k(n-\frac{k(k-3)}2)$.

Since your question allows the summands to be arranged in any order, and since they are all distinct, the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ where $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are distinct nonnegative integers is $k!\,p_k(n-\frac{k(k-3)}2)$; or in your notation:

The number of solutions of $k_1+\cdots+k_n=k$ where $k_1,\dots,k_n$ are distinct nonnegative integers is
$$n!\,p_n(k-\frac{n(n-3)}2).$$

Comment: (+1) Please find an independent verification of your formula by Polya counting below.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I've found a solution, but it's up to you all to check its correctness. 
Here it goes:

We have to find the number of non-negative integral solutions to :$$k_1+k_2+....+k_n=P$$
where $k_i\in \{ 0,1,2,3,.....\}$ , $P\in\{1,2,3,4,....\}$ and $k_i\ne k_j$

Since all the numbers in LHS are distinct, we can assume for simplicity that  $k_i<k_{i+1}$

With this assumption, let:$$k_1=k_1+0$$$$k_2=k_1+a_1$$$$.$$$$.$$$$.$$$$k_n=k_{n-1}+a_{n-1}$$
where $a_i\in \{ 1,2,3,.....\}$

Then,$$k_1+k_2+...+k_n=k_1+(k_1+a_1)+(k_1+a_1+a_2)+...+(k_1+a_1+...a_{n-1})$$
$$k_1+k_2+...+k_n=nk_1+(n-1)a_1+(n-2)a_2+...+2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$$
So we got to find the solutions to$$nk_1+(n-1)a_1+(n-2)a_2+...+2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}=P$$
Since I don't know how to deal with natural numbers, I rewrite the equation as$$nk_1+(n-1)b_1+(n-2)b_2+...+2b_{n-2}+b_{n-1}=P-\binom{n}{2}$$
where $b_i\in \{0,1,2,3,.....\}$

Now very easily we can write the multinomial in which we will have the coefficient of $x^{P-\binom{n}{2}}$ as the number of solution sets. Which we can multiply by $n!$ to get the desired number of tuples. 
I give the final answer as $C$ multiplied by $n!$ , where $C$ is the coefficient of $x^{P-\binom{n}{2}}$ in the expansion of 
$$(1+x^n+x^{2n}+...+x^{n\lfloor\frac{P-\binom{n}{2}}{n}\rfloor})(1+x^{n-1}+x^{2n-2}+...+x^{(n-1)\lfloor\frac{P-\binom{n}{2}}{n-1}\rfloor}).....(1+x+x^2+....+x^{P-\binom{n}{2}})$$
**NOTE**: If it's not visible, the power of $x$ in the last terms of the brackets has a floor function. If it's still not clear, it's ${n\lfloor\frac{P-\binom{n}{2}}{n}\rfloor}$ in the first bracket, and then you just keep on decreasing n by 1 in the subsequent brackets.

### CHECKING THE FORMULA

First, let's take your first case where $n=3$ and $P=4$.
The  expression will be $(x^0)(x^0)(x^0)$ in which the coefficient of $x^0$ is 1. Which we multiply by 3! to get the answer 6.

Now let's take your second case where $n=2$ and $P=6$. 
The expression will be $(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$ in which the coefficient of $x^5$ is 3. Which we multiply by 2! to get 6.

Answer (score 1):

It is not my area of expertise, but I believe that what you are after are called in the literature *compositions of* $k$ *into* $n$ *distinct parts*.

You can probably find the answer in the following 1995 paper by B.Richmond and A.Knopfmacher "Compositions with distinct parts" ([link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01827930)), to which I unfortunately have no access.

The generating function for the number of composition of $k$ into $n$ distinct parts is also given at the very end of the following [preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0693.pdf) and a close formula could possibly be derived from it.

Answer (score 0):

If $k_i$ are not distinct then the total ways are:
$$\sum_{i}^nk_i=k,k_i\ge0\longrightarrow \binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$$
Now we need to use inclusion-exclusion to remove cases where any two or more $k_i$'s are equal, note that you need to be more careful while using inclusion-exclusion because when taking for example $k_1$ and $k_2$ equal there may be the case that $k_3=k_4,k_1\ne k_3$, not even that for it may be that at the same time groups of 2,3 and 4 elements are equal and this may require much work which I skip here.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion leads to the cycle index and is the actual meat of this problem, which was skipped in this answer

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a closed-form solution, but here is a straightforward recurrence that admits a slow $O(nk^2)$ dynamic programming solution in $O(k^2)$ space. Let $f_n(k,m)$ be the number of sorted solutions to $k_1 + \cdots + k_n = k$ with $k_1 \le \cdots \le k_n \le m$, then

$$f_n(k,m) = \sum_{k' = 0}^{\min(m,k)} f_{n-1}(k-k',k'-1)$$

Base case is $f_1(k,m) = [k \le m]$.

Since each integer is distinct, the number of solutions with any ordering is $n! f_n(k,k)$.