# Number of positive unequal integer solutions of $x+y+z+w=20$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, diophantine-equations, combinations, linear-diophantine-equations

What is the number of positive different integer solutions of $x+y+z+w=20$, where $x,y,z,w$ are all different and positive?

It would be nice if coding is not used.  I am given the answer $552$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Each solution of the desired type is a permutation of a solution in which $x<y<z<w$, and every permutation of such an increasing solution is of the desired type. Each increasing solution has $4!=24$ permutations, so you need only count the increasing solutions and multiply by $24$.

**Added:** This can be done fairly easily by brute force. For other methods see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002344/number-of-positive-integral-solutions-to-xyzw-20-with-xyzw-and-x-y-z?rq=1). To see what **Marc van Leeuwen** is doing in his answer, note that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{1-x}&=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\\
\frac1{1-x^2}&=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\ldots=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{2n}\\
\frac1{1-x^3}&=1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\ldots=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{3n}\\
\frac1{1-x^4}&=1+x^4+x^8+x^{12}+\ldots=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{4n}
\end{align*}$$

If you take the product of these, each term in that product (before you collect like terms) will be of the form

$$x^{k_1}x^{2k_2}x^{3k_3}x^{4k_4}=x^{k_1+2k_2+3k_3+4k_4}\tag{1}$$

for some non-negative integers $k_1,k_2,k_3$, and $k_4$. When you combine like powers of $x$, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ will be the number of terms like $(1)$ in which $k_1+2k_2+3k_3+4k_4=10$. Finally, there is a bijection between such $4$-tuples $\langle k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4\rangle$ and partitions of $10$ into parts of sizes $1,2,3$, or $4$: $k_i$ is the number of parts of size $i$. And as Marc had already briefly explained, the number of such partitions is equal to the number that we want. You may find it helpful to look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)); when Marc talks about Young diagrams, he’s talking about what the article calls Ferrers diagrams.

Comment: Is it by taking $x1$=$x$-1, $y1$=$y$-2, and so on so u get $x1+y1+z1+w1$=10 so the no of solutions is 23??

Comment: @Harish: Yes, that’s essentially the method used by **Marc van Leeuwen** in his answer to the question to which I linked in the addition to my answer.

Comment: Yes i understood most of that but why is it 1/1−X×1/1−X2×1/1−X3×1/1−X4??            I did not get that part and i couldn't ask him because of my lack of reputations

Comment: @Harish: Have you done any work yet with generating functions?

Comment: @Harish: That makes it pretty difficult to explain what he was doing there. Let me see if I can add something to my answer to give you at least the general idea.

Comment: @Harish: Okay, see if that at least gives you the idea of what he’s doing.

Comment: Yes it does.But i am still trying to figure.If there isn't any easier way then i would suggest you not to search one.This pretty enough for beginners and anyways thanks

Comment: @Harish: You’re welcome. There really isn’t an easier way: counting partitions is hard.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - I have been trying to find a faster method to find the coefficient of $x^10$ while solving this particular question(seems like every Indian competitive maths textbook has one in it), because what I was left with at the end of finding the generating function for the solution to the equation $$4x+3y+2z+t=20, \text{where} x,y,z,t\ge1$$ is $$x^{10}\cdot\dfrac{1-x^{20}}{1-x^4}\cdot\dfrac{1-x^{18}}{1-x^3}\cdot\dfrac{1-x^{20}}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{1-x^{20}}{1-x}$$ And finding the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the generating function is proving to be a tough task for me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - It was supposed to be $x^{10}$ instead of $x^10$ in the first line.

Comment: @user350331: I don't offhand know of a nice way to get that coefficient, I'm afraid. But if you're working on the same problem, I'm now sure why you have that expression instead of just the product of the four functions in my answer. (I'll have only limited computer access for the next few days.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Good thing I came online at the right time. I ended up asking [Marc van Leeuwen](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1002520/350331) the same question, and looks like he gave a somewhat programming centered method which I have been trying to understand for quite some time, actually I am pretty new to programming only have som much knowledge of MathJax(if we consider that programming)

Answer (score 6):

By inclusion-exclusion over the distinctness conditions:

There are $\binom{20-1}3=\binom{19}3$ solutions disregarding the conditions.

There are $\binom42$ ways to choose one pair that fails to be distinct, with common value $k$, and $19-2k$ options for the remaining two values, for a total of

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^9(19-2k)&=9\cdot19-2\cdot\frac{9(9+1)}2\\
&=81\;.
\end{align}

There are $3$ ways to choose two non-overlapping pairs that fail to be distinct, and $\binom{10-1}1=9$ options for their values, and $12$ ways to choose two overlapping pairs that fail to be distinct, so that three values are equal, and then $6$ different options for the values.

There are $\binom{\binom42}3=\binom63$ ways to choose three pairs, of which $4$ constrain only $3$ values to be equal, leading to $6$ options as above, and the remaining $\binom63-4$ constrain all $4$ values to be equal, leaving only $1$ option.

For $k=4,5,6$, there are $\binom{\binom42}k=\binom6k$ ways to choose $k$ pairs, all of which constrain all $4$ values to be equal and thus leave only $1$ option.

Thus by inclusion-exclusion the total count is

$$
\binom{19}3-\binom42\cdot81+3\cdot9+12\cdot6-4\cdot6-\left(\binom63-4\right)+\binom64-\binom65+\binom66=552\;.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison with Brian Scott's solution, here is the longhand count solution.

As is observed in several places above, it is sufficient to find the number of solutions with $x<y<z<w$ and multiply by 24, because each such solution can be permuted to give 24 solutions to the original question.

Next note that $1+2+3+4=10$ is the smallest total for 4 unequal positive integers, so we are not going to get many solutions. Now $4+5+6+7>20$, so $x=1,2$ or 3. Since $3+4+5+6=18$ the only possible solutions for $x=3$ are $(3,4,6,7),(3,4,5,8)$.

Similarly for $x=2$ we must have $y=3,4$ or 5. $y=5$ gives only $(2,5,6,7)$. $y=4$ gives only $(2,4,6,8),(2,4,5,9)$. $y=3$ gives only $(2,3,4,11),(2,3,5,10),(2,3,6,9),(2,3,7,8)$.

Finally in a similar way $x=1$ implies $y=2,3,4,5$ and gives solutions $(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,13),(1,2,5,12),(1,2,6,11),(1,2,7,10),(1,2,8,9)$ and $(1,3,4,12),(1,3,5,11),(1,3,6,10),(1,3,7,9)$ and $(1,4,5,10),(1,4,6,9),(1,4,7,8)$, and $(1,5,6,8)$.

Total 23, hence 552 to question.

--------- shorter version ------

I have spelt this out in full detail, but note that since only the count is required setting out all those cases with $z+w=k$ is not really needed. It is enough to say something like:

$x=3$ implies $y=4$ and 2 solutions

$x=2$ implies: $y=3$, 4 solutions; or $y=4$, 2 solutions; or $y=5$, 1 solution

$x=1$ implies: $y=2$, 6 solutions; or $y=3$, 4 solutions; or $y=4$, 3 solutions; or $y=5$, 1 solution.

Total 23 solutions. Times 4! gives 552 to the original question.

----------- comment ----------

Teachers often give simple questions for you to practice methods like generating functions. But simple questions can often be answered faster by more elementary methods. Often fastest is best!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best Solution I found when I was preparing for IIT-JEE 2000-2003.
suppose equation is $x + y +z + t = N$
find $k= [(N-2n-4)/2]$, where n is the least integer present is the solution.
for example to find number of solutions in which least number present is $1$, put $n=1$.
Now draw the following diagram
[image]
Stop when $1$ comes.
Now If $N$ is even add lower row terms along with middle row terms and multiply the sum with $4!$. This is the number of unequal integral solution of above equation having n as the least integer.
If $N$ is odd add upper row terms along with middle row terms and multiply the sum with $4!$.
Repeat the process for other possible values of $N$.
In above case $n$ can have values $0, 1, 2$, & $3$, if we are interested in finding non-negative unequal integral solutions, because $4 + 5 + 6 + 7 > 20$
for $n=0$, there are $24\times 4!$ solution
for $n=1$, there are $14\times 4!$ solutions
for $n=2$, there are $7\times 4!$ solutions
and for $n=3$, there are $2\times 4!$ solutions.
Total number of non-negative solutions can be obtained by adding all$= 1128$
If you are interested in only positive unequal integral solutions drop the case of n=0, and you get $552$
If you wish to obtain solution for $x, y, z, t > 1$, drop the case $n=0$ and $n=1$ both, and you get $216$. 
and so on.......