# Combinatorics] Partition Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $R(n,k)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ (non-empty) parts.

That is for example $R(7,2) = 3$ because it can be expressed as $1+6, 2+5$ and $3+4$.

Prove that:

$R(n,1) +R(n,2) + ... + R(n,k) = R(n+k,k)$

Workings:

LHS counts the number of ways partitions there are of $n$ by breaking it into $1$ to $k$ parts.

RHS counts the number of partitions there are of $n+k$ into $k$ parts.

That's about all I know. So any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Hint: Ferrer's Diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Take any partition of $n+k$ into $k$ parts and subtract $1$ from each part. What do you get? Is the process reversible?

Comment: Would you have $R(n+k-1, k-1) + R(n+k-2, k-2) + ... + R(n+k-k,k-k)?$ This process can be reversed by adding $1$'s There was a hint given that I forgot to post earler Ferrer's Diagram

Comment: @hockeynl: Look at a single partition of $n+k$ into $k$ parts. When you reduce each part by $1$ you get a partition of what into what? My hint can actually be understood in terms of Ferrers diagrams. If you start with the Ferrers diagram of a partition of $n+k$ into $k$ parts, and you remove the lefthand column, you get the Ferrers diagram of ... what?

Comment: Okay so I was playing around with Ferrer's diagram and it seems like that there is a partition of $n$ into $L$ nonempty parts, where $L$ is the number of parts in the original partition whose sizes are at least $2$.

Comment: @hockeynl: More to the point, you get a partition of $n$ into **at most** $k$ parts. How does that compare with your LHS?

Comment: LHS counts partitions of $n$ that goes from $1$ up to $k$ parts

Comment: @hockeynl: Exactly: the partitions of $n$ into **at most** $k$ parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18810/discussion-between-hockeynl-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @hockeynl: Okay; I’m there.

Comment: @hockeynl: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This problem merits special attention because it is an instance of a partition problem that can be solved by the Polya Enumeration Theorem as well as by Ferrer's diagrams.

Using the material from this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999319/)
we have for the sum on the LHS the equality

$$\sum_{q=1}^k P_q(n)
= \sum_{q=1}^k [z^n] Z(S_q)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)
= [z^n] \sum_{q=1}^k Z(S_q)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$
where $Z(S_q)$ is the cycle index of the symmetric group.

Recall that the OGF $G(w)$ of the cycle indices $Z(S_q)$ is given by
$$G(w) = \exp\left(a_1 w + a_2 \frac{w^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{w^3}{3} + a_4 \frac{w^4}{4} + \cdots\right)$$

This gives for the sum the formula
$$[z^n] [w^k] \frac{1}{1-w} 
\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} \frac{w^q}{q}\right)$$
where the factor $1/(1-w)$ implements the summation.

Re-write this as
$$[z^n] [w^k] \exp\log\frac{1}{1-w}
\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} \frac{w^q}{q}\right)
\\ = [z^n] [w^k] 
\exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w} +\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} \frac{w^q}{q}\right) 
\\ = [z^n] [w^k] 
\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1}\frac{w^q}{q} +
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{1-z^q} \frac{w^q}{q}\right) 
\\ = [z^n] [w^k] 
\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-z^q} \frac{w^q}{q}\right).$$
This can be evaluated by inspection and yields
$$[z^n] Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= [z^{n+k}] z^k Z(S_k)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= [z^{n+k}] Z(S_k)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right) = P_k(n+k),$$
thus completing the proof.

I do think this is remarkably pretty.