# Distribution of K balls in N Cells with limitations

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In how many ways can i distribute $k$ balls in $n$ numbered cells with the following limitations:

1.Each cell has different number of balls in it

2.Given each cell has more balls than the cell before it
(My guess was that it is the soulution for 1 divided by 2)

For example the answer for $k=5$ $n=3$ for 1. will be 4 and for 2. will be 2

Comment: Can the first cell be empty?

Comment: Would love to know a general answer-what happens if it's empty and if it doesn't

Comment: condition 2 includes condition 1 so condition 1 is redundant

Comment: For (2) divide the answer for (1) by $n!$.  Maybe that is what you meant.  But I would lean towards solving (2) first.

Comment: (2) is the number of partitions of $k$ into $n$ distinct parts, plus (if you allow zero balls) the number of partitions of $k$ into $n-1$ distinct parts.

Comment: For 1) it's the number of subsets of $\mathbb N$ such that $|A|=\sum_{i\in A}1=n$ (or $n+1$ if we allow one to be empty) and $\sum_{i\in A}i=k$. There is no explicit formula for this number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way  of enrichment I would like  to point out that  using the Polya
Enumeration Theorem the closed form is also given by

$$n! [z^k] Z(P_n)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$$

where  $Z(P_n) = Z(A_n)-Z(S_n)$  is the  difference between  the cycle
index of  the alternating group and  the cycle index  of the symmetric
group. This cycle index is known in species theory as the set operator
$\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ and the species equation here is

$$\mathfrak{P}_{=n}\left(\mathcal{Z} +  \mathcal{Z}^2 +
\mathcal{Z^3} + \cdots\right).$$

Here we  have chosen  the interpretation where  none of the  cells are
empty.

Recall  the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(P_n)$ of
the set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ on $n$ slots, which is
$$Z(P_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l-1} a_l Z(P_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$
This recurrence lets us calculate the cycle index $Z(P_n)$ very easily.

For example when $n=3$ the cycle index is
$$Z(P_3) = 
1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}-1/2\,a_{{2}}a_{{1}}+1/3\,a_{{3}} $$
and the generating function becomes
$$1/6\,{\frac {{z}^{3}}{ \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{
3}}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) }}+1/3\,{\frac {
{z}^{3}}{-{z}^{3}+1}}$$
which gives the sequence
$$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 42, 48, 60, 72,\ldots$$
which is six times [OEIS A069905](https://oeis.org/A069905).

Similarly when $n=5$ we get the cycle index
$$Z(P_5) = 
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}}{120}}-1/12\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{
3}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}\\-1/4\,a_{{4}}a_{{1}}-1/
6\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}+1/5\,a_{{5}}$$
and the generating function becomes
$${\frac {{z}^{5}}{120\, \left( 1-z \right) ^{5}}}-1/12\,{\frac {{z}^
{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}+1/6\,{
\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{2}
}}\\+1/8\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( 1-z \right)  \left( -{z}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}-1/4\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{4}+1 \right)
 \left( 1-z \right) }}\\-1/6\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{ \left( -{z}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( -{z}^{3}+1 \right) }}+1/5\,{\frac {{z}^{5}}{-{z}^{
5}+1}}$$
which gives the sequence
$$\ldots,120, 120, 240, 360, 600, 840, 1200, 1560, 2160, 2760, 
3600,\ldots$$
which is $120$ times [OEIS A001401](https://oeis.org/A001401).

There are many more related links at 
[MSE Meta on Burnside/Polya](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868#13335).

The Maple code for these was as follows.

```
pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
        local p, s;
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l-1)*
        a[l]*pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

q :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
    local gf;

    gf := pet_varinto_cind(z/(1-z), pet_cycleind_set(n));
    n!*coeftayl(gf, z=0, k);
end;
```

This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999319/) has a computation that is just about the same.

Comment: i wished there was a simpler way of doing this ;)