# Counting binary strings of length $n$ that contain no two adjacent blocks of 1s of the same length?

Tags: combinatorics, binary, combinatorics-on-words

Is it possible to count exactly the number of binary strings of length $n$ that contain no two adjacent blocks of 1s of the same length? More precisely, if we represent the string as $0^{x_1}1^{y_1}0^{x_2}1^{y_2}\cdots 0^{x_{k-1}}1^{y_{k-1}}0^{x_k}$ where all $x_i,y_i \geq 1$ (except perhaps $x_1$ and $x_k$ which might be zero if the string starts or ends with a block of 1's), we should count a string as valid if $y_i\neq y_{i+1}$ for every $1\leq i \leq k-2$.

Positive examples : 1101011 (block sizes are 2-1-2), 00011001011 (block sizes are 2-1-2), 1001100011101 (block sizes are 1-2-3-1)

Negative examples : 1100011 (block sizes are **2-2**), 0001010011 (block sizes are **1-1**-2), 1101011011 (block sizes are 2-1-**2-2**)

The sequence for the first $16$ integers $n$ is:  2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 45, 83, 154, 285, 528, 979, 1815, 3364, 6235, 11555, 21414. For $n=3$, only the string 101 is invalid, whereas for $n=4$, the invalid strings are 1010, 0101 and 1001.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "two consecutive blocks of 1's of the same length"?

Comment: @inavda The string **should not** contain a substring of the form 01{k}0+1{k}0, i.e. a block of 1s of some length $k$, followed by one or more zeros and then by another block of 1s of the same length $k$.

Comment: that is, the blocks of $1$ contained are all of different length ?

Comment: @GCab They can be of the same length if they are not adjacent. 1101011 is a valid string for $n=7$.

Comment: Any two equal length blocks of 1s must be separated by more than a single 0. Is how I read it. Or possibly must have a block of 1s between them. This is unclear. Is 110011 valid, or are the two 11s considered adjacent?

Comment: What I understand is that if $0^{x_1}1^{y_1}\cdots 0^{x_n}1^{y_n},$ then $y_{i}\neq y_{i+1}.$

Comment: Basically $110011$ is not allowed but both $1100111$ (diff length) and $1101011$ (same length but there is another sequence of $1$ in between) are allowed.

Comment: and also $110011$ is valid ? but not $110110$?

Comment: @GCab 110011 is not valid, because two adjacent blocks of 1's have the same length.

Comment: @Phicar Yes, I will edit the question with your notation.

Comment: @GCab you need at least one sequence of $1$ of diff length in between for $2$ sequence of $1$ to have same length.

Comment: Are you interested only in exact results, or also about approximations for large $n$ ?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1956058/573047) to a simpler problem using generating functions could give some useful idea.

Comment: A few sequences that are surprisingly close but not exact matches in the OEIS: http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+4%2C+7%2C+13%2C+24%2C+45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm your results for $n \le 16$.  It might be useful to compute the values by conditioning on $k\in\{1,\dots,\lfloor(n+3)/2\rfloor\}$:
\begin{matrix}
n\backslash k & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
3 & 1 & 6 & 0 \\ 
4 & 1 & 10 & 2 \\ 
5 & 1 & 15 & 8 & 0 \\ 
6 & 1 & 21 & 22 & 1 \\ 
7 & 1 & 28 & 48 & 6 & 0 \\ 
8 & 1 & 36 & 92 & 25 & 0 \\ 
9 & 1 & 45 & 160 & 77 & 2 & 0 \\ 
10 & 1 & 55 & 260 & 196 & 16 & 0 \\ 
11 & 1 & 66 & 400 & 437 & 74 & 1 & 0 \\ 
12 & 1 & 78 & 590 & 883 & 254 & 9 & 0 \\ 
13 & 1 & 91 & 840 & 1652 & 726 & 54 & 0 & 0 \\ 
14 & 1 & 105 & 1162 & 2908 & 1818 & 239 & 2 & 0 \\ 
15 & 1 & 120 & 1568 & 4869 & 4116 & 857 & 24 & 0 & 0 \\ 
16 & 1 & 136 & 2072 & 7819 & 8602 & 2627 & 156 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix}

Maybe try inclusion-exclusion together with stars-and-bars?  For fixed $k$, the first term of inclusion-exclusion is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to
$$\sum_{j=1}^k x_j + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} y_j = n - (k-2) - (k-1) = n-2k+3,$$
which is
$$\binom{(n-2k+3) + (2k-1)-1}{(2k-1)-1} = \binom{n+1}{2k-2}.$$
For $k\in\{1,2\}$, this formula is correct.  For $k \ge 3$, it is only an upper bound.

---

An alternative approach is to condition on the tail $(y_{k-1},x_k)$.  Explicitly,
let state space
$$S_n = \left\{k \in \{1,\dots,\lfloor(n+3)/2\rfloor\}, y \in \{[k\not=1],\dots,n\}, x \in \{0,\dots,n-y-2k+5\}\right\}.$$
For $(k,y,x) \in S_n$, let
$f_n(k,y,x)$ be the number of such binary strings that end in $1^y 0^x$.  Then $f$ satisfies the recursion
$$f_n(k,y,x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $n = 0$} \\
[y = 0 \land x = n] &\text{if $k = 1$} \\ 
\sum\limits_{\substack(k-1,y_{k-2},x_{k-1}) \in S_{n-y-x}:\\ y_{k-2} \not= y \land ((y_{k-2} \ge 1 \land x_{k-1} \ge 1) \lor k=2)} f_{n-y-x}(k-1,y_{k-2},x_{k-1}) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The desired values are then $\sum\limits_{(k,y,x) \in S_n} f_n(k,y,x)$.

Comment: Might be messy to program with all the conditions, but I guess this dynamic programming approach is the best we can get. Nice diligent work !

Comment: @Nocturne thanks.  I did code it up to make sure it is correct.  What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

An aproximation for large $n$

The runs of $0$s and $1$s can be approximated by iid geometric random variables (with $p=1/2$, mean $2$). Hence we have in average $n/2$ runs, of which $n/4$ are runs of $1$s.

Then, the problem is asymtpotically equivalent to : given $m=n/4$ iid Geometric variables $X_1, X_2 \cdots X_m$ find $P_m=$ probability that $X_{i+1} \ne X_i$ for all $i$.

This does not seem a trivial problem, though (and I haven't found any reference).

A crude aproximation would be to assume that the events $X_{i+1} \ne X_i$ are independent. Under this assumption we get

$$P_m \approx P_2^{m-1}= (2/3)^{m-1} \tag 1$$

This approximation is not justified, and it does not seem to improve with $n$ increasing.

The exact value can be obtained by a recursion on the probabilities for each final value, which together with a GF gives me this recursion :

$$P_m = r(1,m) $$

$$r(z,m)= \frac{1}{2z-1} r(1,m-1) - r(2z,m-1) \tag 2$$

with the initial value $r(z,1)=\frac{1}{2z-1}$

Finally, the total number of valid sequences is $C_m = P_m \, 2^n$ ($n=4m$)

I've not yet found an explicit or asympotic for $(2)$.

Some values oc $C_m$

```
n    m  r(2)            iid(1)          exact
4    1  16              16              13
8    2  170.6           170.6           154
12   3  1950.5          1820.4          1815
16   4  21637.3         19418.1         21414
20   5  243540.2        207126.1        252680     
24   6  2720810.9       2209345.3       2981452
28   7  30515606.3      23566350.0      35179282
```

Comment: The values for $n\in\{17,\dots,28\}$ are $$39688, 73558, 136333, \color{red}{252680}, 468314, 867962, 1608659, \color{red}{2981452}, 5525763, 10241348, 18981131, \color{red}{35179282}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here I am going to use generating functions like in [this answer to a related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1956058/573047) to compute columns of @RobPratt table for $k \ge 3$.

We can define:

$$S_y(k,i) = \left\{\text{n. of solutions for} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} y_j = i \text{ with } y_j \neq y_{j+1}\right\} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

and then scompose the problem as follows:

$$\left\{\text{n. of solutions for} \sum_{j=1}^k x_j + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} y_j = n-2k+3 \right\}=\\ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2k+3}\left\{\text{n. of solutions for} \sum_{j=1}^k x_j = n-2k+3-i \right\}S_y(k) =\\ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2k+3}{n-k+2-i \choose k-1}S_y(k,i) \tag{2}\label{2}$$

When $k=3$, the problem of determining $S_y(k,i)=S_y(3,i)$ is all the same as in the above linked problem, only with $2$ variables instead of $4$. Instead of repeating all calculations we can reuse the above answer, removing all terms with an exponent for $y$ greater than $2$, to get the generating function:

$$f(x)=\left[\frac{y^2}{2!}\right]\prod_{n\ge0}(1+yx^n) = \left[\frac{y^2}{2!}\right]\left( 1+\frac y{1-x}+ \frac12\frac{y^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)\left( 1-\frac12\,\frac{y^2}{1-x^2}\right)=\\ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\{\frac 12 \left[1+(-1)^{n+1}\right]+n\right\}x^n$$

where in the last step I have used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+of+1%2F%281-x%29%5E2-1%2F%281-x%5E2%29+at+x+%3D+0) because I am lazy, and then:

$$S_y(3,i) = [x^i]f(x) = \frac 12 \left[1+(-1)^{i+1}\right]+i \tag{3}\label{3}$$

OK, yes, using generating functions for $k = 3$ and $y_1+y_2=i$ is a little overkill, because the $\eqref{3}$ result is obvious (once we choose a value for $y_1$, and this can be done in $i+1$ ways, then $y_2$ is determined; after that the first addendum is needed to discard the $y_1=y_2=i/2$ solution when $i$ is even).
Anyway, replacing in $\eqref{2}$ we obtain the formula for the third column of @RobPratt table:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}{n-1-i \choose 2}\left\{\frac 12 \left[1+(-1)^{i+1}\right]+i\right\}=\\ \frac 1{48} (2 n^4 - 8 n^3 + 4 n^2 + 8 n + 3 (-1)^n - 3)\tag{4}\label{4}$$

where again I have used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28n-1-i%29%28n-2-i%29%2F2%28%281%2B%28-1%29%5E%28i%2B1%29%29%2F2%2Bi%29+for+i%3D0...n-3) for the last step (verified against @RobPratt table [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F48+%282+n%5E4+-+8+n%5E3+%2B+4+n%5E2+%2B+8+n+%2B+3+%28-1%29%5En+-+3%29+for+n%3D3...16)).

Still thinking how to extend this to $k \gt 3$...

Answer (score 2):

Consider a binary string  with $s$ ones and $m$ zeros in total.
Let's put an additional (dummy) fixed zero at the start and at the end of the string.
We individuate as a *run* the consecutive $1$'s between two zeros, thereby including runs of null length. With this scheme we have a fixed number of $m+1$ runs.

[image: Bernoulli_runs_2]

The number of different strings with the  above numbers of zeros and ones is obviously
$$
\left( \matrix{  m + s \cr   s \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{  m + 1 + s - 1 \cr   s \cr}  \right)
$$
which corresponds to the [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
of $s$ into $m+1$ parts.

The number of compositions of $s$ into $k$ non-null parts (*strong* compositions) is instead
$$ \binom{s-1}{k-1} $$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( \matrix{  m + s \cr   s \cr}  \right)
 = \sum\limits_{\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,\min \left( {m + 1,s} \right)} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  s - 1 \cr   k - 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,\min \left( {m + 1,s} \right)} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  m + 1 \cr  m + 1 - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  s - 1 \cr   k - 1 \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$

So we can concentrate on strong compositions with no equal consecutive parts.
Consider the strong composition of $s$ into $k$ parts, the last of which is $r$
$$
\left[ {r_{\,1} ,\,r_{\,2} ,\; \cdots ,\,r_{\,k - 1} ,r\;} \right]
\quad \left| {\;r_{\,1}  + \,r_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + \,r_{\,k - 1}  + r = s} \right.
$$
whose number is
$$
C_T(s,k,r) = \left[ {k = 1} \right] + \left( \matrix{  s - r - 1 \cr   k - 2 \cr}  \right)
 = \left( \matrix{  s - r - 1 \cr   s - r - k + 1 \cr}  \right)
\quad \left| \matrix{  \;1 \le k \le s \hfill \cr   \;1 \le r \le s \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).
Then the sum over $r$ will correctly give
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{r = 1}^s {C_T (s,k,r)}
  = \sum\limits_{r = 1}^s {\left( \matrix{  s - r - 1 \cr   s - r - k + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{s - 1}
 {\left( \matrix{  j - 1 \cr   j - k + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {k - 1\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,s - 1} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  s - 1 - j \cr   s - 1 - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  j - 1 \cr  j - k + 1 \cr}  \right)}
  = \left( \matrix{  s - 1 \cr   s - k \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$

Let's indicate with $C_G (s,p,r), \; C_B (s,p,r)$ the number of good and bad strong compositions of $s$ into  $p$ parts the last of which
equal to $r$.

Then we have the relations
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  C_T (s,p,r) = \left[ {1 \le p \le s} \right]\left[ {1 \le r \le s} \right]\left( \matrix{
  s - r - 1 \cr 
  s - r - p + 1 \cr}  \right) \hfill \cr 
  C_G (s,1,r) = C_T (s,1,r) = \left[ {r = s} \right]\quad C_B (s,1,r) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  C_G (s,p,r) + C_B (s,p,r) = C_T (s,p,r) \hfill \cr 
  C_B (s,p,r) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{s - r} {C_B (s - r,p - 1,k)}  + C_G (s - r,p - 1,r) =  \hfill \cr 
   = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{s - r} {C_B (s - r,p - 1,k)}  - C_B (s - r,p - 1,r) + C_T (s - r,p - 1,r) \hfill \cr 
  C_G (s,p,r) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{s - r} {C_G (s - r,p - 1,k)}  - C_G (s - r,p - 1,r) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

In particular for the good strong compositions we can write the recurrence
$$
C_G (s,p,r) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{s - r} {C_G (s - r,p - 1,k)}  - C_G (s - r,p - 1,r) + \left[ {1 = p} \right]\left[ {r = s} \right]
$$

After computing $C_G$, we can sum on $r$ and then go back along the previous steps
to compute the good weak compositions in terms of $s,m$ and finally the number in $n$,
i.e.:
$$
N_G (n) = \sum\limits_{s = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{p = 1}^{n - s + 1}
 {\left( \matrix{  n - s + 1 \cr   p \cr}  \right)
\sum\limits_{r = 1}^s {C_G (s,p,r)} } } 
$$
which in fact for $0 \le n \le 16$ gives
$$
0, \, 1, \, 3, \, 6, \, 12, \, 23, \, 44, \, 82, \, 153,
 \, 284, \, 527, \, 978, \, 1814, \, 3363, \, 6234, \, 11554, \, 21413
$$
not counting as good the all zeros string.

Comment: @Robpratt: thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 2):

I am gonna attempt to complement **RobPratt**'s proposed approach involving inclusion exclusion and stars and bars and be that person who posts a horribly long formula.
Consider $$A_{n,k,r}=\left |\left \{0^{l_1}1^{k_1}\cdots 0^{l_r}1^{k_r}0^{l_{r+1}}\in \{0,1\}^n: k_i>0,k_i\neq k_{i+1}, \sum _{i=1}^rk_i=k \text{ and for $i\neq 1,r+1,$ }l_i>0\right \}\right |.$$ Our desired result will be $$A_n=\sum _{k=0}^n\sum _{r=0}^nA_{n,k,r}.$$
Notice that we can, by the multiplication principle, express $A_{n,k,r}$ as
$$A_{n,k,r}=|B_{n,k,r}|\times |C_{k,r}|,$$
where $$B_{n,k,r}=\left \{(l_1,\cdots ,l_{r+1})\in \left (\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}\right )^{r+1}:\sum l_i=n-k, l_i>0 \text{ for $1<i<r+1$}\right \}$$
represents the way to place the $0'$s and $$C_{k,r}=\{(k_1,\cdots ,k_r)\in \left (\mathbb{Z}^{> 0}\right )^{r}:\sum k_i=k,k_i\neq k_{i+1}\}.$$
represents the way to place the 1's.
By stars and bars we get that  $|B_{n,k,r}|=\binom{n-k-(r-1)+(r+1)-1}{(r+1)-1}=\binom{n-k+1}{r}.$ Now, consider the following set $C_{k,r,x}=\{(k_1,\cdots k_r)\in C_{k,r}:k_x=k_{x+1}\}$ which carries the words with at least one consecutive chunk of 1's of the same size(at index $x$). To illustrate the next step, notice that $|C_{k,r,x}|=\sum _{t=1}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\binom{k-2t-1}{r-2-1},$ for any $1\leq x<r$ by assuming the summands at position $x$ and $x+1$ are the same, this value is given by $t.$
We can then express $$C_{k,r}=\binom{k-1}{r-1}-\sum _{\ell =1}^{r-1}(-1)^{\ell -1}\sum _{X\in \binom{[r-1]}{\ell}}\left | \bigcap_{x\in X} C_{k,r,x}\right |,$$
but now the problem starts again because we need to know how many chunks of elements(consecutive) are in the set $X$ for us to be able to know how many summands are equal. When we know this, we can use stars and bars.  Call thr number of chunks $s$ and call the size of $i-$th chunk $\ell _i.$ Notice that we want $\ell _i>0$ and $\sum \ell _i=\ell.$ We then associate a number $t_i$ to be the number in the summand of all elements in the $i-$th chunk (for a total contribution of $(\ell _i+1)t_i$ to the whole sum). We get then that
$$C_{k,r}=\sum _{\ell =0}^{r-1}(-1)^{\ell}\sum _{s = 0}^{\ell}\sum _{\substack{ \ell_1+\cdots +\ell_s=\ell \\ \ell _i,t_i>0}}\binom{r-1-\ell -(s-1)+(s+1)-1}{s+1-1}\binom{k-\left (\sum _{i=1}^s(l_i+1)t_i\right )-1}{r-(\ell+s)-1}.$$
Putting all this together we get
$$A_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^n\sum _{r=0}^n\binom{n-k+1}{r}\sum _{\ell =0}^{r-1}(-1)^{\ell}\sum _{s = 0}^{\ell}\sum _{\substack{ \ell_1+\ell_2+\cdots +\ell_s=\ell \\ \ell _i,t_i>0}}\binom{r-\ell}{s}\binom{k-\left (\sum _{i=1}^s(l_i+1)t_i\right )-1}{r-(\ell+s)-1}.$$
In this formula,by the combinatorial interpretation, treat $\binom{-1}{-1}=1.$
Using *sage* I get the sequence $2,4,7,13,24,45,83,154,\dots.$
For the moment I do not see any way to make this less painful.

---

Another approach that might yield to something. Construct the DFA associated with that language (fix the maximal number of chunks to be $n$ and the maximum number of $1's$ in each chunk to be $k.$) The DFA looks like an $k\times n$ array and consider the [Chomsky-Schutzenberger technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem) One has to solve a system of $k(n-k)$ equations and then try to take the limit as $n,k$ go to $\infty.$ The system to solve in variables $R_{i,j}\in \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ looks like
$$R_{i,j}=\begin{cases}xR_{i,j+1}+xR_{j,0}+[i\neq j] & \text{If }j>0\\
xR_{i,1}+xR_{i,0}+1 & \text{If }j=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't $A_{n,k,r}$ require $k_i \not= k_{i+1}$?

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Phicar Nice ! Guys, I was not expecting such an enthusiasm, can you vote on whose answer I should accept ?

Comment: @Nocturne Is a really nice and challenging problem. Thanks for sharing! Go for the one that please you the most. :).