# Count the number of possible solutions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

We want to choose 5 natural numbers from 1 to 13. (Non-repetitive numbers) 
And also sum of these numbers must be greater than 40 . How many solutions we have ? (using combination or any other operator that can help)

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \gt 40$   and     $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\{1,2,3,\dots , 13\}$

Comment: The answer is 280.

Comment: Oh ! How you got this number ?

Comment: Hint: first find how many combinations add up to *less* than 40.

Comment: I can't do anything with your help. If you can write on paper and take photo.

Comment: @S.H.W For finding out the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 <= 40$, let $x_6>0$, then observe that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 <= 40$ has solutions same as  $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 +x_6= 40, x_6>0$. Now, since since you know the no. of solutions of <=40, you can deduce those of >40, since $x_is$ take only a limited range of values.

Comment: @bat_of_doom Why $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \le 40$ has same solutions as $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 40$ , $x_6 \gt 0$ ?

Comment: @TorsionSquid Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: @S.H.W Because, if $x_6>0$, then the other terms have to add up to a number strictly less than 40. For example, sample solution: 1 1 1 1 35 1 then the other terms add up to 39. And this covers all possible solutions.

Comment: Numbers must be Non-repetitive.

Comment: @bat_of_doom  Please explain your idea with complete answer.

Comment: Here is a one-line Matlab code to find the correct answer: `sum(sum(nchoosek(1:13,5),2)>40)`

Comment: Thank you but I have list of answers and I need solution !

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999319/how-solutions-of-distinct-non-negative-solutions-are-there-to-k-1-cdotsk-n-k

Comment: @msm Thank You , It is good source but I want to choose numbers from 1 to 13 and also sum of $x_i$ must be greater than 40 and none of that answers hasn't these conditions.

Comment: You should search more on this website. There are several examples that explain how to convert inequality to equality. I think someone also suggested that in the comments...

Comment: @msm Yes , I did it But can't find something like this. If you can write the answer.

Comment: @TorsionSquid You know the right answer , I checked it with Mathematica. Can you explain your answer completely and step by step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an interpretation of @TorsionSquid's answer according to OPs  comment.

> We use the technique of *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function)* to encode the number of ordered five-tuples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ of integer values with the constraints
>   \begin{align*}
> 1\leq x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5\leq 13\qquad \text{and}\qquad x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5>40
> \end{align*}
>
> The integer values $i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,13\}$ are encoded as power of a formal variable $z$ and the number of occurrences of $i$ is given as the coefficient of $z^i$.

The expression
\begin{align*}
1+z^i
\end{align*}
represents the integer value $i$ which occurs either zero or one times. Whenever we select a five-tuple $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$  we select $5$ different values between $1$ and $13$ inclusively. This corresponds to five factors from the product
\begin{align*}
(1+z^1)(1+z^2)(1+z^3)\cdots(1+z^{13})=\prod_{i=1}^{13}(1+z^i)
\end{align*}

> We now introduce a new variable $t$ to *mark* the factors we choose. If we write
>   \begin{align*}
> (1+tz^1)(1+tz^2)(1+tz^3)\cdots(1+tz^{13})=\prod_{i=1}^{13}(1+tz^i)
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain a generating function $A(z,t)$ which can be expanded in powers of $t$ 
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{13}A_i(z) t^i
> \end{align*}
>   with $A_i(z)$ being polynomials in $z$.

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[t^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ in a series. Since we have to consider all five-tuples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ we take the coefficient of $t^5$ from $A(z,t)$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^5]A(z,t)=[t^5]\prod_{i=1}^{13}(1+tz^i)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   If we evaluate the RHS of (1) at $z=1$ we have all solutions of
>   \begin{align*}
> x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\qquad\text{with}\qquad 1\leq x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5\leq 13\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   But we need only those solutions with $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5>40$. This corresponds to the summands of $A(z,t)$ with powers of $z$ greater then $40$.

Here is a somewhat closer look at the situation with the help of Wolfram Alpha

> \begin{align*}
> [t^5]&A(z,t)=[t^5]\prod_{i=1}^{13}(1+tz^i)\\
> &s=[t^5]\sum_{i=0}^{13}A_i(z) t^i
> =A_5(z)\\
> &=t^5z^{15}\left(z^{40}+z^{39}+2z^{38}+3z^{37}+5z^{36}+7z^{35}+10z^{34}+13z^{33}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad+18z^{32}+22z^{31}+28z^{30}+33z^{29}+40z^{28}+45z^{27}+52z^{26}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad+\cdots\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad+18z^8+13z^7+10z^6+7z^5+5z^4+3z^3+2z^2+z+1)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Since we need $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5>40$ we consider the coefficients of $z^n$ with $n>40$ only. The term $z^{15}$ is factored out in (3). So we need all summands in (3) starting with $52x^{26}$ up to $z^{40}$. In order to isolate these summands we can divide the polynomial (3) by $z^{41}$ and focus on the summands with non-negative powers. This means we subtract the *[principal part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_part#Laurent_series_definition)*, which is the  part with negative powers.

> We obtain this way 
>   \begin{align*}
> z^{14}&+z^{13}+2z^{12}+3z^{11}+5z^{10}+7z^{9}+10z^{8}+13z^{7}\\
> &\qquad+18z^{6}+22z^{5}+28z^{4}+33z^{3}+40z^{2}+45z^{1}+52
> \end{align*}
>   Finally evaluating this expression at $z=1$ counts the number of occurrences of  (2) and gives
>   \begin{align*}
> 1&+1+2+3+5+7+10+13\\
> &\qquad+18+22+28+33+40+45+52=280
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Your answer is complete and also complex! Can you provide some references for better understanding ? Because I'm a high school student.

Comment: @S.H.W: I recommend *[Lectures on Integer Partitions](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf)* which is a good starter for studying integer partitions based upon generating functions. Another accessible starter  is *[Integer Partitions](https://www.amazon.com/Integer-Partitions-George-E-Andrews/dp/0521600901)*, by G. E. Andrews. (t.b.c)

Comment: @S.H.W: This is the little brother of his classic *[The Theory of Partitions](https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Partitions-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/052163766X)*. A great starter with respect to generating functions is Wilf's *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)*. You might also find *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)* useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take the coefficient of $t^5$ in

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{13} (1+tx^i);
$$

call it $p(x)$. Take $p(z)/z^{41}$, subtract the principal part, and plug in $z=1$. Voilá!

Comment: Can you explain more ? What do you mean by $t$ and $z$ ?

Comment: They're formal variables.

Comment: Is it related to specific theory ?

Comment: Frankly , I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Please help me to understand your answer. I really need to find the answer.