# Generalize diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

We have this equation :
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n = c $$

How we can find number of non repetitive solutions in natural numbers or integer numbers ?

Comment: This is an application of the stars and bars argument.  In this case, it is ${c+n-1} \choose {c}$

Comment: Can you show the proof of this expression ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics shows how to use the bars and stars idea, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29 has proofs and more general information.

I won't reprove them as there is a lot of information, proofs, and examples using it and solving generalized diophantine equations, but these links will help you understand the method.

Comment: @AndroidFish How we can use this formula for this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040444/count-the-number-of-possible-solutions