# Finding distinct integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + ...+ x_r = n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many different (distinct $x_i$) non-negative integer solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + ...+ x_r = n$ have?

We know that it has $n+r-1 \choose r-1$ non negative solutions. But how many are different?

actually I want to solve this problem...
choose 5 card from 13 cards that every cards marked with number 1 to 13 .
how many way sum of chosen cards if greater than 40.
so i want to know how many distinct solution that equation has. because we have only one card from each one.

then i'm going to calculate this for n= 41 to 55

Comment: Different in what way? Not permutations of one another?

Comment: I assume we should read $r$ instead of $5$ and that $C(n,k)$ stands for the binomial coefficient $(n,k)$.

Comment: @C.Falcon: $C(n,k)$ is a fairly standard variant of $\binom{n}k$; $(n,k)$ is not.

Comment: Or are you requiring the $x_i$ to be distinct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I recognize my point was not clear, I meant the binomial coefficient associate to the pair (or of index) $(n,k)$.

Comment: @C.Falcon: Ah, okay; I misunderstood.

Comment: All the solutions are different. (Unless you mean **distinct**, $x_i\neq x_j$.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes i want to x_i to be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

> *Hint:* The question addressing the special case $r=13, 41\leq n \leq 65$ already has an answer  *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040444/count-the-number-of-possible-solutions/2047282#2047282)*.

Answer (score 0):

use generating functions, consider integer $i$ can be chosen or not. If we choose it, it contributes $yx^i$ ; if not it contributes $1$. so the answer is

$$r![x^ny^r]\prod_{i=0}^n(1+yx^i)$$

use ferrers diagram we can prove that
$$[y^r]\prod_{i=1}^n(1+yx^i)=\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{x^i}{1-x^i}$$

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
Coefficient[
 Series[Product[x^i/(1 - x^i), {i, 1, r}] + 
   Product[x^i/(1 - x^i), {i, 1, r - 1}], {x, 0, n}], x, n] r!
```